# I am new to coding. if user give wrong input how can we ask to reenter input without exiting code?

Tags: java, loops, exception, user-input

My question is that when user gives wrong input it throw exception msg "wrong input" and exits the code. I want to ask again to enter the input without exiting code. I tried while loop but I didn't do it right, so please help with my doubt.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      
      try {  System.out.println("enter");
      int a=sc.nextInt();
      int b=sc.nextInt();
           System.out.println(a+b);
          
      } catch (Exception e) {
          //TODO: handle exception
          System.out.println("wrong input");
          System.out.println("enter again");
         
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand what a while loop is? Your code sample doesn't seem to loop in any manner at all...

Comment: @sittsering please delete your comment then

Answer (score 1):

Use while loop and break.

```
while (true)
{
    try {
        System.out.println("enter");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a + b);
        break;
       } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("wrong input");
            System.out.println("enter again");
            sc.nextLine();
       }
}
```

Only when both `a` and `b` values are entered correctly, then it'll break out of `while` loop, otherwise it'll keep looping.

Comment: thnks. I didnt add sc.nextLine(); while trying while loop